# React Bootstrap : Expected a component class, got button. Each component name should start with an uppercase letter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I am getting 
  **"Expected a component class, got button. Each component name should start with an uppercase letter"**  
when i run the following code. any thing wrong with this code, Please let me know.
[image]

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class LayoutApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button >Close</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('LayoutApp', () => LayoutApp);
```

Thanks .

Comment: Can you show us the code of the View class please?

Comment: React Bootstrap component only react not react-Native
recommend react Native component
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons and https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native

Answer (score 0):

React Bootstrap is not compatible with React Native.